Landlord demanding access for non emergency painting
Brooklyn NYC.
Theoretically, let's say a Landlord is demanding access to a painter to touch up/paint some windows and doors, because he feels like it.
The paint is the same as it is since I moved in a few months ago. If it's relevant, let's say  Apartment was also empty long before tenant moved in and many renovations were made.
It's definitely not an emergency, just something he wants to do. Let's say It's the very beginning of the rent lease term, so he does not need to show it to any other tenants, he just wants to touch up some paint that he forgot to do before renting the apartment out.
What are the rights as a tenant in terms of allowing him to enter? Can he demand entry within 24 hours or must it be no less than a week? Would it make a difference what the lease says?

Please explain the down vote! What's wrong with this question?

Two down votes. No explanation

What does the lease say about routine preventative maintenance?

The downvotes are probably because questions asking for legal advice are off-topic here (i.e. questions which apply to a specific real-life situation that you are in). The question is very likely to be closed once it picks up enough votes. You can edit or re-post it generically, making sure to remove all references to your personal circumstances (e.g. "What are a tenant's rights when a landlord demands access to a property for non-emergency repairs?", or "Can a tenant refuse access to a landlord for a non-emergency repair?" etc.).

Provided the comply with the notice period, they can access to make repairs
new-south-wales
For non-urgent repairs (like painting), the minimum notice period is 2 business days.

Even when correct notice has been given, there are limits to when a landlord, agent or authorised person can enter the property without the tenant’s consent.

In most circumstances, entry is not permitted on Sundays, public holidays or outside the hours of 8am to 8pm

Where practical, landlords should notify tenants of an approximate day and time when entry will be required

The landlord, agent or authorised person should not stay on the property longer than necessary

If the landlord or agent’s authorised person (e.g. a selling agent, valuer or tradesperson) wants to enter the property, they must have written consent from the landlord or agent and must show this to the tenant if the tenant is home.



They can also access without notice if the tenant gives permission.

Question is about NYC. Are you sure it's not one week minimum?

@Tenant This asnwer is tagged New South Wales (Australia), so its not relevant to your situation. Its still a good answer because it might be relevant to some future person who does live in NSW.

Ok. But it wouldn't be relevant as an answer to this question :)

@Tenant On Law.SE, it is explicitly allowed/encouraged to provide answers for other jurisdictions than a question is tagged for (saves having one question for each jurisdiction).

@TripeHound but it's evil
